# c# WCF host.open failing

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, net.tcp

I am doing a WPF application and it is also a WCF server, the problem I have is that I need the ServiceHost to be open and listen in a port for the clients and accept requests as soon as it starts, but the problem I have is that if I write the code to open the host *host.open* in the constructor after the function  *this.InitializeComponent()*, it fails with an exception. If I open the host in a button and I press it after the app started, it works without any problems.

Why is that and how can I resolve this issue?

I am utilizing a tcp.net channel,I am hosting it in the application and  the exception I receive is about the service already was registered.

The exception on the clients is:

> inner exception message :"An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host"
>   error number: 10054
>  
>   Socket error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.ConnectionReset

thanks

Wally

the constructor is:

```
public Window1()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   starthost();  
}

private void starthost()
{
   host = new ServiceHost(typeof (Window1), 
                           new Uri[]{ new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000") });

   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGanador), new NetTcpBinding(), "Contador");
   host.open(); //it fails with this line here but not in a button 
}
```

Comment: What's your code like? If I had to guess, I'd say it sounds like you're putting code such that it ends up running twice.

Comment: I found out System.ServiceModel is calling my window1 constructor everytime it receives a client request, is this a Microsoft Bug? or is that  the expected behavior ?
it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No, you probably have the default "per-call" instancing mode on. That's the expected behavior - each request from the client will fire up an instance of the server.

Answer (score 3):

So do I get this correctly? Your "Window1" is a WPF window class, which implements the service contract IGanador? That seems a bit odd.... how about just creating a class of its own, e.g. "GanadorService", which implements IContador? Then this **CLASS** would be created / instantiated for each request - not your window.

```
public Window1()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   starthost();  
}

private void starthost()
{
   host = new ServiceHost(typeof (GanadorService), 
                           new Uri[]{ new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000") });

   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGanador), new NetTcpBinding(), "Contador");
   host.open(); //it fails with this line here but not in a button 
}


public class GanadorService : IGanador
{
   .... (whatever methods you need) .....
}
```

That should help, I hope!

Marc

Comment: I did it like that because I need to change the gui and I wasn't sure  how to pass a handle of my window to the class implementing the interface for the Servicehost. Because I don't call the constructor but the ServiceModel does it directly.   is there a way to do that?       thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
I resolved the problem thanks a lot to the comments of marc_s
I created a singlenton servicehost 
adding the following attribute to my window1 
     [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

and passing this in the constructor: 
 host = new ServiceHost(
                          this ,
                           new Uri[]{
                                    new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000                                                                    });

it works great because I only have one client anyway
thanks
this is a link with a great article with the explanation of WCF instance managment: 

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. When using Message contract type as parameter, Only one parameter can be used in service Operation

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   void SaveEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails emp);
   ```
2. Service operation either should return Messagecontract type or it should not return any value

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   EmployeeDetails GetEmployeeDetails();
   ```
3. Service operation will accept and return only message contract type. Other data types are not allowed.

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   EmployeeDetails ModifyEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails emp);
   ```

Note: If a type has both Message and Data contract, service operation will accept only message contract.